# Calculating Field of how many intersections each feature makes?

Tags: python, count, calculator, selection, intersection

FC = Feature Class

I have points and lines in two separate FCs representing regional projects (We can call them `line_projects` and `point_projects`). I need each project scored by how many polygons are intersected from the top Quartile of a selected demographic field. There are 5 of theses demographic fields needing to be analyzed. All demographic fields are in a single feature class called Census_Layer.

```
import arcpy

# Set workspace and feature class names
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\path\to\workspace.gdb"
point_projects = "point_projects"
line_projects = "line_projects"
census_layer = "Census_Layer"

# Set demographic fields to analyze and their quartile values
dem_fields = ["field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5"]
quartile_values = [1234, 5678, 9101, 1121, 3141] # example quartile 
values

# Loop through each demographic field
for i in range(len(dem_fields)):
dem_field = dem_fields[i]
quartile_value = quartile_values[i]

# Create where clause to select features with attribute value >= 
quartile value
where_clause = "{} >= 
{}".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(census_layer, dem_field), 
quartile_value)

# Intersect point and line projects with selected demographic 
features
intersect_output = "intersect_{}_{}".format(point_projects, 
line_projects)
arcpy.analysis.Intersect([point_projects, line_projects, 
census_layer], intersect_output, where_clause)

# Create dictionary to store project scores
project_scores = {}

# Loop through point and line projects and count intersecting 
polygons
for proj_fc in [point_projects, line_projects]:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(proj_fc, ["OID@", "score_field"]) as 
cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            proj_oid = row[0]
            intersect_count = int(arcpy.management.GetCount("{}\\OID@ 
= {}".format(intersect_output, proj_oid))[0])
            project_scores.setdefault(proj_oid, 
[]).append(intersect_count)

# Update score fields for each project based on sum of intersection 
counts
for proj_fc in [point_projects, line_projects]:
    score_field = "score_field"
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(proj_fc, ["OID@", score_field]) as 
cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            proj_oid = row[0]
            if proj_oid in project_scores:
                scores = project_scores[proj_oid]
                final_score = sum(scores)
                row[1] = final_score
                cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Then I get this error:

```
ExecuteError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [14]:
Line 11:    arcpy.analysis.Intersect(["point_projects", "line_projects", fc2], intersect_output, where_clause)

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py, in Intersect:
Line 525:   raise e

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py, in Intersect:
Line 522:   retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.Intersect_analysis(*gp_fixargs((in_features, out_feature_class, join_attributes, cluster_tolerance, output_type), True)))

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py, in <lambda>:
Line 512:   return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))

ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of NO_FID | ONLY_FID | ALL.
Failed to execute (Intersect).
```